# Spring Boot. Different errors hanldilng for @Ccontroller and @RestController in one app

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, error-handling

I have normal @Controller and @RestController in one App.
How it possible to handle erros in Json for REST, and redirect to error page for normal @Controller?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the Spring Annotation @ExceptionHandler in your controller and throw Exceptions in your controller logic. For an short example I will use Java's RuntimeException. You could define your own exception and throw them

```
// your controller classes
@Controller
public class MyController {

  @ExceptionHanlder(RuntimeException.class)
  public String errorInController(){

   // for your custom page
   return "yourDefineErrorTemplatePage";

   // if you want to redirect to the default spring page
   // return "redirect:/error";
 }

 @RequestMapping("yourFirstEndpoint")
 public String getPage(){

    if(yourLogicHere){
         throw new RuntimeException("Display error page");
    }
    return "myPage";
 }
}
```

Your @RestController could look like the following:

```
@RestController
public class RestControllerClass{

  @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
  public ResponseEntity<Error> errorOccured(){

       // you can return just a String or define your own 'error object'
       Error error = new Error("Some error occured");
       return new ResponseEntity<Error>(error, Http.Status.NOT_FOUND);

 }

 @RequestMapping("yourSecondEndpoint")
 public ResponseEntity<YourEntity> getPage(){

    // the entity you want do return as json
    YourEntity yourEntity = new YourEntity();

    if(yourLogicHere){
         throw new RuntimeException("Display error page");
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<YourEntity>(yourEntity, HttpStatus.OK);
 }

}
```

Example for the Error Object:

```
public class Error{

   private String errorMessage;

   public Error(String errorMessage){
      this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
   }
}
```

I hope this small example can solve your Problem.

For more details visit: https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Nice first answer!